# httpd authentication - LDAP group

Tags: apache, ldap, active-directory-group

I have a restricted section of a website that I want to restrict to two LDAP groups. Here are the pertinent lines from httpd.conf:

```
<AuthnProviderAlias ldap our-ldap>
  AuthLDAPBindDN CN=example,OU=example,OU=example,DC=example,DC=com
  AuthLDAPBindPassword LamePassword
  AuthLDAPURL ldaps://dc4.example.com:636/dc=example,dc=com?sAMAccountName?sub
  AuthLDAPGroupAttributeIsDN on
</AuthnProviderAlias>

<Directory /var/www/html/restricted>
  Order deny,allow
  Allow from all
  AuthBasicProvider our-ldap
  AuthType Basic
  AuthName "Restricted Files"
  Require ldap-group CN=group1,OU=example,OU=example,DC=example,DC=com
  Require ldap-group CN=group2,OU=example,OU=example,DC=example,DC=com
</Directory>
```

If I comment out those two "Require ldap-group" lines, it works flawlessly, but with any LDAP user, which I don't want. When I add those lines back in, despite the fact that I'm a member of one of those groups, I can't get in, and ssl_error_log gives me this:

```
[Sat Jun 28 21:34:53 2014] [error] [client 198.51.100.156] access to /restricted/restricted.html failed, reason: require directives present and no Authoritative handler.
```

My LDAP server is an Active Directory domain controller, so usernames are *sAMAccountName*, DNs are *distinguishedName*, and group member attributes are *member*, using DNs.

Here's what I'm running:

```
Server version: Apache/2.2.15 (Unix)
Server built:   Mar 20 2014 06:21:02
```

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

You're requiring the user to be a member of *both* groups. You need a Satisfy Any.